# can't create an AI model version in google cloud - missing permissions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, permissions, google-ai-platform

When trying to create a version for a newly created AI model, I get this error:
You are missing at least one of the following required permissions:

Project

ml.versions.create

In the troubleshoot page, it looks like I do have this permission:

"permission is in role:"

```
"role": "roles/ml.admin",
  "members": [
    "user:myemail@gmail.com"
    ]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you by any chance deploying the AI model from an existing bucket in a different project? That scenario may require granting additional permissions to the AI Platform Prediction service account: https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/deploying-models#store-your-model

Answer (score 1):

After [installing the Google Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install) on my local machine and uploading a model using its `gcloud` command-line tool, it started working from the Cloud Console as well.